# Uploaded file to Sharelatex, can it be automatically updated when updating locally?

Tags: external-files, sharelatex

So i am using the *mcode.sty* package in Sharelatex to import my MATLAB files into my project, works great! But when I want to edit some of the code, I need to re-upload the updated code file..

Is there any way to directly link my locally stored file with Sharelatex, so it will be automatically updated when edited and saved in MATLAB?

Cheers!

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShareLaTeX offers synchronization with Dropbox and GitHub, though not in the free plan:

- https://www.sharelatex.com/user/subscription/plans